# How to read tab-delimited fields into an array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have file HOMO.txt with this content:

```
   1506      -4.6242      2.00000
```

I am using below commands:

```sh
$ mapfile -t myArray < HOMO.txt
$ echo ${myArray[0]} 
1506 -4.6242 2.00000
$ echo ${myArray[1]}
```

The last command is returning a blank line. What I want is, to assign the middle value to a variable. Can anybody please suggest a fix.

Comment: `mapfile -td' ' array < file.txt; echo "${array[1]}"`

Comment: Yep, since it is just one-line `read` can handle it, at least in bash with the `-a` flag.

Answer (score 0):

By default mapfile uses newline as element delimiter. You can change it to space `" "` with the `-d` option like follows.

```
mapfile -t -d " " myArray < HOMO.txt
echo ${myArray[0]}
echo ${myArray[1]}

# Output
1506
-4.6242
```